# Topcoat vs Bootstrap 3 performance in a PhoneGap app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cordova, twitter-bootstrap-3, topcoat

I'm coding a hybrid HTML5 app. Now I'm in the stage of choosing my tools. I've had few doubts that you already help me to clear up. But after discovering [Topcoat](http://topcoat.io/) I have this one last question.

I already know that since [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) reached version 3 and you can strip it directly in the webpage, it becomes much more fluent. But the fact that Topcoat is just CSS made me think because a lot of people still complain about Twitter Bootstrap + Phonegap performance...

Has anyone here made a real test to determine how fluid / natural the experience is, and which one handles better?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I tested both Boostrap 3 and Topcoat Slider SideMenu, and compared them using the event time tracker of Google Chrome. Topcoat gives me a better performance.